# Migrating from AOL 9.1 to Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, aol

I am trying to move someone from AOL 9.1 Desktop client to Outlook 2007. I tried just redownloading all of the mail using IMAP in Outlook but it didn't download some of the messages, which I assume were stored in the AOL 9.1 Personal Filing Cabinet.

Does anyone have a suggestion on this migration process. The machine with AOL is running XP home and the Outlook 2007 machine is running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: "I am trying to move someone from AOL 9.1 Desktop client to Outlook 2007." you don't like this person very much, do you? sounds like going from bad to worse :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution involves **[ePreserver](http://www.connectedsw.com/Overview/57266)**, a commercial application ($25):

**[How do I export my America Online (AOL) Address Book and Email?](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_export_my_america_online_aol_address_book_and_email.html)**